# Unable to Detect GPU after installing CUDA

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have followed all the steps mentioned to install **CUDA** and **cuDNN** for **Tensorflow-GPU** but the command
`tf.test.is_gpu_available(cuda_only=False, min_cuda_compute_capability=None)`
gives False

Also while running the model I get `cudart64_101.dll`
even though I have installed **CUDA** and configured the paths.

Currently I'm using a RTX2070

Comment: Couldn't it be driver problem? Did you install driver for your graphic card?

Comment: yes I've installed the driver for graphics card provided on Nvidia's website. is there something else too that i need to install?

Comment: If you are using anaconda install tensorflow using conda. It automatically installs the correct version of cudnn and the cuda toolkit.. Pip does not.

Comment: Used this method and it worked. Thanks a lot. Also it seems that version of python also need to be specified. It doesn't seem to be working for 3.8 and needed python 3.7 for cuda 10